# What is the purpose of TThread.FinishThreadExecution, and when is it called?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, tthread

I've been trying to implement a thread that runs in the background and updates a progress bar every second or so and following the example in the top answer to [Delphi - timer inside thread generates AV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244848/delphi-timer-inside-thread-generates-av). I notice that the proposed solution has an implementation of TThread.FinishThreadExecution. My IDE shows that my version of delphi supports that method, but I've been unable to find any documentation on it (google turns up 10 hits, none of which help, http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/ doesn't list that method under TThread. What is it for and when is it called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FinishThreadExecution` is not a method inherited from the `TThread` base class. It is only a method implemented in the derived class, `TTimerThread`.

The purpose of the method is to finish the execution of the thread in a proper way.

All `FinishThreadExecution` does is to call `Terminate`, which sets an internal flag in the TThread, plus sets the `FTickEvent` event to wake the thread. The thread execute method will then end and the thread will self destruct, since `TThread.FreeOnTerminate` is true.

Comment: I must have typed the declaration on autopilot - now I notice the declaration and the point where it's called. Don't I feel like a fool now. Thanks for setting me straight so quickly.