# How to create a timer in a lib for mobile app using Delphi XE5?

Tags: delphi, mobile, timer, delphi-xe5

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a timer in a library for a mobile app using Delphi XE5. The code shown here [Delphi - timer inside thread generates AV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244848/delphi-timer-inside-thread-generates-av) cant be used as I don't know any reference of the instansiated object of my library to use synchronize on.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a threaded timer you can use as the original timer component - but it is not a component

```
uses
  ...
  ThreadTimer;

type
  TForm1 = class( TForm )
  private
    FTimer : TTimerThread;
    procedure TimerOnTimer( Sender : TObject );
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
    procedure BeforeDestruction; override;
  end;

procedure TForm1.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  FTimer := TTimerThread.Create;
  FTimer.OnTimer := TimerOnTimer;
  // FTimer.Interval := 5000;
  // FTimer.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  inherited;
  FTimer.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.TimerOnTimer( Sender : TObject );
begin
  // Do whatever you like in here

end;
```

and here the complete unit

```
unit ThreadTimer;

interface

uses
  System.Classes,
  System.SyncObjs;

type
  TTimerThread = class( TThread )
{$REGION 'Constants'}
  private const
    C_DEFAULT_INTERVAL = 1000;
    C_DEFAULT_ENABLED = True;
{$ENDREGION}
{$REGION 'Syncronization'}
  private
    FCS : TCriticalSection;
    FEvent : TEvent;
{$ENDREGION}
  private
    FInterval : Cardinal;
    FOnTimer : TNotifyEvent;
    FEnabled : Boolean;
    function GetInterval : Cardinal;
    procedure SetInterval( const Value : Cardinal );
    function GetOnTimer : TNotifyEvent;
    procedure SetOnTimer( const Value : TNotifyEvent );
    function GetEnabled : Boolean;
    procedure SetEnabled( const Value : Boolean );
  protected
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    property Interval : Cardinal read GetInterval write SetInterval default C_DEFAULT_INTERVAL;
    property OnTimer : TNotifyEvent read GetOnTimer write SetOnTimer;
    property Enabled : Boolean read GetEnabled write SetEnabled default C_DEFAULT_ENABLED;
  end;

implementation

{ TTimerThread }

constructor TTimerThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create( False );
  FCS := TCriticalSection.Create;
  FEvent := TEvent.Create( nil, False, False, '' );
  FInterval := C_DEFAULT_INTERVAL;
  FEnabled := C_DEFAULT_ENABLED;
end;

destructor TTimerThread.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
  FEvent.Free;
  FCS.Free;
end;

procedure TTimerThread.Execute;
var
  LInterval : Cardinal;
begin
  inherited;
  while not Terminated do
    begin

      FCS.Enter;
      try
        if FEnabled
        then
          LInterval := FInterval
        else
          LInterval := INFINITE;
      finally
        FCS.Leave;
      end;

      if ( FEvent.WaitFor( LInterval ) = wrTimeout )
      then
        Synchronize(
            procedure
          begin
            if Assigned( OnTimer )
            then
              OnTimer( Self );
          end );
    end;
end;

function TTimerThread.GetEnabled : Boolean;
begin
  FCS.Enter;
  try
    Result := FEnabled;
  finally
    FCS.Leave;
  end;
end;

function TTimerThread.GetInterval : Cardinal;
begin
  FCS.Enter;
  try
    Result := FInterval;
  finally
    FCS.Leave;
  end;
end;

function TTimerThread.GetOnTimer : TNotifyEvent;
begin
  FCS.Enter;
  try
    Result := FOnTimer;
  finally
    FCS.Leave;
  end;
end;

procedure TTimerThread.SetEnabled( const Value : Boolean );
begin
  FCS.Enter;
  try
    if FEnabled <> Value
    then
      begin
        FEnabled := Value;
        FEvent.SetEvent;
      end;
  finally
    FCS.Leave;
  end;
end;

procedure TTimerThread.SetInterval( const Value : Cardinal );
begin
  FCS.Enter;
  try
    if FInterval <> Value 
    then
      begin
        FInterval := Value;
        FEvent.SetEvent;
      end;
  finally
    FCS.Leave;
  end;
end;

procedure TTimerThread.SetOnTimer( const Value : TNotifyEvent );
begin
  FCS.Enter;
  try
    FOnTimer := Value;
  finally
    FCS.Leave;
  end;
end;

procedure TTimerThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
  inherited;
  FEvent.SetEvent;
end;

end.
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `FEvent.Free; FCS.Free;` must be **after** inherited. Otherwise if the thread is running and you call `Free` the inherited destructor calls `Terminate` and that call `TerminatedSet` and that fires the event - uups, which event ... you already freed it ... Also inside `Execute` is still waiting for the event to fire and not to be freed. Please check this unit for yourself with this **before** and **after** `inherited`

Comment: In my opinion then, you've fixed your problem the wrong way. You also reverted the `TForm1.BeforeDestruction` change. I can't upvote code with such traps.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You can fix my code, but please do not break it. In my opinion this is the right way and the right time to free the critical section and event (after `inherited`). It does not matter, if `FTimer` is freed before or after `inherited` in **this** case.

Comment: I am very sorry about breaking it. No argument there. The fact that inherited is on two occasions in a non standard place is a code smell.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It is not, it is a must. Otherwise you can't simply call `Free` because you must call `Terminate` before calling `Free` and that would be a code smell. How should others know this fact.

Comment: Personally I'd use `FreeAndNil`, as I always do, and then test `Assigned(FEvent)`. I can see that would not be to the taste of others. However, if you are going to use non-standard orderings (which is a big code smell in my view), it should be commented for future readers. But I'll put the +1 back because this is certainly very helpful, even if I quibble over the specifics.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Did you have had a look at the inherited destructor code from `TThread`? Dealing with threads is somehow different and it is **not** wise to free an instance when it is possible in use (code in Execute is still running and waiting for the event). After `inherited` the thread has ended for sure and it is safe to free the instances used by the tread. `FreeAndNil` is a valid option but also after the thread has ended

Comment: I understand the issue. Now. I wouldn't solve it the way you did. That's fine. No matter what, the issue deserves comments.

Comment: Thanks for the src and info. It seams to work fine on Android.

Comment: The same thread, placed within a Delphi Android Service, never starts running.